# sql sql server 2012 does not print message

Tags: sql, sql-server, printing

I write the following code to print message:

```
declare @NT1 int
set @NT1 =(SELECT   CompanyID  FROM dbo.CompanyInfo where CompanyID = 101)

if @NT1> 101

print 'Good'
```

After execute this script , I get the following message
Command(s) completed successfully.

I should get message 'Good' after executing the above script. How do I print message?

Thanks

Comment: Why would it print "Good"?  Last time I checked, 101 is not `> 101`.

Comment: Oh Gosh!!! How can you get a value more than 101 when you filtered for 101?

Comment: That's on sql server.  This question is about sql sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```
declare @NT1 int
set @NT1 =(SELECT   CompanyID  FROM dbo.CompanyInfo where CompanyID = 101)

if @NT1 = 101

print 'Good'
```

Answer (score -2):

Forgot else statement:

declare @NT1 int

set @NT1 =(SELECT   CompanyID  FROM dbo.CompanyInfo where CompanyID = 101)

if @NT1 > 101
print 'good'

ELSE
    PRINT 'bad';